Simple neural network applications
I am wondering if there are some applications for simple CNNs and MLPs that are preferred to complex deep neural networks. For example, tabular data is still working with traditional ML algorithms and simple MLPs because its representations are not a matrix. I am thinking of other applications in image, IoT, and cloud.  I have been searching for some papers on Google Scholar and other academic websites, but I have not yet found any papers to convince me about this. From some papers, I realized that some researchers use distillation, running, and different ways of reducing the size of deep neural networks with the least accuracy lost. However, I think there are other applications where complex neural networks are not applicable. Could you please guide me on this topic or give me some references to show that there are still some applications for simple neural networks?
